# SQL IfNull() function doesn't recognize null strings

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jsp, web

i'm developing a database search page (using jsp), in this search page users will have multiple search conditions/options in the form of a drop-down list, those options can be left unselected (null in other words), if they're left unselected the complete column should be retrieved. To achieve this i'm using ifnull() function, and i'm using MySQL.

The problem i'm facing is that SQL can't seem to recognize that the string is null, when a null string is passed in the ifnull function, it retrieves null values instead of retrieving the complete column. Passing NULL directly in the query "ifnull(NULL,Location)" seem to  work just fine.

The List:

```
       <select name="EX">
            <option value="NULL">Any</option>
            <option value="1">Option1</option>
            <option value="2">Option2</option>
            <option value="3">Option3</option>
        </select>
```

How values are handled in the next page:

```
String NameVar = new String();
if(request.getParameter("EX") == "NULL"){
NameVar = null;
}
else if(request.getParameter("EX") != "NULL"){
NameVar = request.getParameter("EX");
}
```

My Query:

```
selectItem = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT Location, ItemType "
                + "FROM DBTEST "
                + "WHERE Location = IFNULL(?,Location)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some details on Sas answer. In SQL a null is a special value, and no int or either string can ever be equal to NULL.

In a query, you must use the special construct `IS NULL` to test for null values because `column = NULL` will never be true.

When using home variables, you must explicitely set them to NULL with the`setNull` method

You do not show how you populate your query, but what you need should no be far from :

```
selectItem = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT Location, ItemType "
            + "FROM DBTEST "
            + "WHERE Location = IFNULL(?,Location)");
if (NameVar == null) {
    selectItem.setNull(1, Types.VARCHAR);
}
else {
    selectItem.setString(1, NameVar);
}
```

BTW, common usages in java recommend that only class names begin with an uppercase, variable names should begin with a lowercase, so `NameVar` should be `nameVar`

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
String sql = "SELECT Location, ItemType "
+ "FROM DBTEST "
+ "WHERE Location = IFNULL(?,Location)";
PreparedStatement prepStat = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
prepStat.setString(1, NameVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try set null:

```
 prepStmt.setNull(1, Types.VARCHAR)
```